# changing text by viewport size

Tags: javascript, css

Newbie needs direction badly.
I have a responsive site with call me buttons. Since a viewer on a desktop machine can't actually press the button to call as a mobile device can, I need the button to state "Call Me" when in mobile viewport and state the phone number when viewed on desktop.

I tried the following javascript but firebug reports errors that confuse the situation.
Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

```
var changeText = document.getElementById("changeText");

if (window.innerwidth >= 1024){
    changeText.write("215-555-1555");
    else changeText.write("Call Me");
}
```

Comment: What are the errors that "confuse the situation"?

Comment: Wouldn't media queries handle this best?

Comment: Also, I don't know if this was a copy/paste issue, but your if should not surround your else

Comment: @Flynn that may well be the whole problem

Answer (score 2):

```
var changeText = document.getElementById("changeText");

if (window.innerWidth >= 1024){
  changeText.write("215-555-1555");
}
else{
  changeText.write("Call Me");
}
```

Your else should not be within your if

Comment: also, innerWidth, not innerwidth

Comment: It seems as if I have been caught by common newbie mistakes.
Thanks for your attention to this question. I went round and round, and round again with it.
I have learned two very valuable lessons from this. (else separated from if & watch the camelCase.

THANKS

Answer (score 2):

You should put else outside if

```
if(){
//code
} else{
//else code
}
```